# What ingredient gives vlaamse mayonnaise that special kick?

Tags: mayonnaise, french-fries

I love Dutch frites, and I particularly like the Flemish Frite Saus called vlaamse mayonnaise that they serve at the Frite shop called VleminckX Sausmeesters on Veotboogstraat (just one block off Kalverstraat, the main walking street down the center of Amsterdam).

What gives it that special kick. It's a bit more tart than American mayonnaise.

Comment: This should probably have a "cuisine" tag, but I'm not sure which cuisine it is... can you comment?

Comment: @Aaronut - the question says Flemish and Dutch, and giving the spelling, I think one of the two or both applies.

Comment: @justkt: Yes, I'm just not sure which.

Comment: I would say that either dutch-cuisine or belgian-cuisine would apply, since this type of frite is popular in both countries. However, my experience is with the Dutch version, though the Dutch refer to the type of mayo that I am describing as "Flemish" mayonnaise, when they translate it.

Comment: Got it.  Here's to our first question on Dutch cuisine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frietsaus is just a special mayonnaise

Commercially it is lower in fat than plain mayonnaise

It has oil, starch (replaces extra oil), whole egg yolk, whole mustard seed, sugar, distiled vinegar, and lemon juice

So the kick is just the extra acid (vinegar and lemon juice), the bite from the whole seed mustard, mixed into a lite sauce, not a heavy greasy mayo

BTW: VleminckX Sausmeesters is just a touristy thing, there are plenty of shops in Holland that serve great fries

Personally I think that potatoes from Europe are a bit plain compared to many other continents/countries. the best I have had are from Fiji, the warm humid conditions make excellent deep frying potatoes, and I suspect they lace the cooking oil with a little coconut oil too :-)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. And yes, you are correct, there are many places that serve outstanding frites (in Amsterdam as well as many other places around the world). I've tried a number of them, and this one place has become my personal favorite (for now).

Comment: Here's [a specific recipe](http://dutchfood.about.com/od/saucesgravies/r/Quickmayonnaise.htm) that sounds like exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @Josh - Seems about right except for egg, should be just egg yolk?

Comment: Yes, that did seem strange. But wikipedia says about mayonnaise, "Some recipes — both commercial and homemade — use the whole egg, including the white." It would help to reduce the fat content, as an alternative to adding starch. (As an added bonus, when eaten with fries you'll actually have a pretty nice balance of carbs from the fries, fat from the yolk and oil, and protein from the white!)

Comment: It seems indeed like a good recipe, but I like my mayonaise more if I add a little pepper.
Adding a tablespoon of water is a good idea if you don't want it to be too greasy.

Comment: Confusing, OP tastes mayonnaise so why is frietsaus (fritessaus) the accepted answer? Dutch mayonnaise is usually quite sweet and soft while Flemish mayonnaise is more sour and salty (it has my preference, but that's probably because I eat it less). Fritessaus is neither of the mayonnaise described, but still good in it's own way (and indeed less fat), though it certainly doesn't come close to Flemish (or Dutch) mayonnaise when it comes to taste. Closest fritessaus that comes to (Dutch) mayonnaise would be "Oliehoorn" in my opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, "vlaamse" simply means "Flemish." All I've been able to find online is sites like [this one](http://www.typically.nl/140/flemish-fries-yes-with-mayo/) which claim that the traditional flemish mayo on fries is actually richer and less sour than the stuff we're used to, so that doesn't give us any hint as to what secret ingredients this particular recipe includes.

However, one of the standard ingredients in mayo is vinegar, which itself is a popular topping for fries in some areas. Extra vinegar would definitely give mayo a tart kick like you're describing. Think of the flavor of salt-and-vinegar potato chips... is that the same sort of kick that this mayo has?

Comment: Could also be some other natural acid source (lemon or lime, for example), or a food additive one (e.g., citric acid). Or maybe stronger vinegar (higher acetic acid content vs. water).

Comment: I have seen a recipe where lemon was called for in vlaamse mayonnaise. However, when I followed that recipe, I did not end of with the substance that I have regularly had on frites. The Dutch also sell tubes of what they call Frite Sauc, which is also very nice, and I'd like to make. Again, it is more tangy (and richer) than regular American mayonnaise.

Comment: It is actually called Fritesaus or Frite Saus. I misspelled the name in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

[Dijon Mustard](http://www.food.com/recipe/belgian-mayonnaise-to-serve-with-frites-339616).

It might be lemon juice as well, but you need a little bit of mustard to get the right balance, in my opinion.  (although, I admit, it's been a few years since I've been to the Netherlands, and I likely haven't been to that specific restaurant)